# x509 cert with email address in subject are different in java .vs net

Tags: java, .net, certificate, x509, asn.1

I have a website with multiple web applications that relies on the end user authenticating with their x509 client certificate. We are observing that the same certificate, when processed by a .Net application, shows a different Subject DN than when processed by a Java application, when the DN contains an e-mail address attribute.

In .Net, I see the server variable CERT_SUBJECT like this:

```
C=US, S=Delaware, L=Wilmington, O=IDFC Dev, OU=Test, CN=Richard Sand, E=rsand@idfconnect.lan
```

In Java, when I explore the x509 certificate object for the same cert (same browser session), the subject is:

```
EMAILADDRESS=rsand@idfconnect.lan, CN=Richard Sand, OU=Test, O=IDFC Dev, L=Wilmington, ST=Delaware, C=US
```

Ignoring the reversed order of the attributes (which is a known phenomenon), the problem we're having is that in Java the e-mail address attribute is *EMAILADDRESS* whereas in .Net the same attribute shows as *E*.

Digging further, OpenSSL shows this output:

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -in my.pfx -info

subject=/C=US/ST=Delaware/L=Wilmington/O=IDFC Dev/OU=Test/CN=Richard Sand/emailAddress=rsand@sidfconnect.lan
```

Whereas when I view the same certificate in either the IE or Firefox certificate stores, they show E=, e.g.:

```
E = rsand@idfconnect.lan
CN = Richard Sand
OU = Test
O = IDFC Dev
L = Wilmington
S = Delaware
C = US
```

I know it may seem trivial to just shim in some code to change one "interpretation" of the Subject DN to the other, but the problem is we have two COTS products that we cannot alter, and before we start hacking around the problem I want to understand which (or are both?) correct and if there is something on some layer that is causing the discrepancy. The RFCs all seem to reference EMAILADDRRESS, but as said both IE and FF as well as the .Net app all seem to be using "E"

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: As @pedrofb mentioned in his answer `E` and `EmailAddress` are synonyms. Each platform may specify its own translation of OID. As for the subjects they are not completely different. It's just that one is in reverse order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`E` and `EMAILADDRESS` are synonyms.

When an electronic mail address is embedded in the subject distinguished name (deprecated, should be used subject alternative name extensions) it uses the identifier `pkcs-9-at-emailAdress` defined in PCKS#9 ([RFC2985](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2985)).

It means the emailAddress is not stored with a string `E` or `EMAILADDRESS`,  but as an ASN.1 structure with the identifier `1.2.840.113549.1.9.1`, and what .NET, Java or IE are showing is a representation of this attribute.

If you want to check if the subject of a certificate  match, you need to compare each RDN field, not the string.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for that answer, that makes sense and gives me confidence to normalize on one or the other (as said I can't actually modify the back-end app, which is really the culprit because its configured with a regex to match on the string, and isn't looking at ASN.1 values).

Comment: Happy to help. Consider to mark the answer as correct or upvote when you have enough reputation